# JQuery identify current CSS background-image in three-state icon/button?

Tags: jquery, css, background-image

I have three images being used to indicate an application icon state and I'm attempting to use css to do this.

No problem with the original or hover states:

```
#myDIV {
background-image: url(icons/homeBlack.png);
}

#myDIV:hover {
background-image: url(icons/homeWhite.png);
}
```

but I need to do two other things:
1) when the item is clicked it should use the third image

```
 $("#myDIV").click(function(event){

// change this button
$(this).css("background-image", "url(icons/homeBlue.png)");

});
```

2) if it is clicked again it should not apply the third image again because it's already applied - so it needs to check if it has been applied

My questions are:
1) simply am I missing a css trick somewhere or is Jquery the best way to do this?
2) can I check which background-image is in place and how?

I can't seem to find anything in JQuery that would allow me to determine which image is "currently" in place.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I'm confused, what happens when it has been clicked then you hover then mouseout. I'm guessing it reverts back to the state before it was clicked.

Comment: Accidentally posted instead of commented ... hopefully they delete the post as it isn't a real answer. Anyhow: Have you looked at the jQuery tristate checkbox plugin? 
http://code.google.com/p/jquery-tristate-checkbox/
You can change the bindings all you'd like (and it easly changes from requiring an unordered list)

Comment: Use `addClass` in the click function, if it has the class, it wont add it again. Have the style in a stylesheet.

Comment: Wait, after re-reading, are you looking for the `:visited` css selector?

Comment: @nick the hover no longer works - but for my purposes that's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @zzzzBov I had assumed that :visited would retain that state, but in this case the reason for wanting to determine the image currently in place was to revert to the original image under other conditions ie if another icon was clicked then revert to the original state for this icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create 3 CSS classes:

```
.state_1 {background-image: url(icons/homeBlack.png)}
.state_2 {background-image: url(icons/homeWhite.png)}
.state_3 {background-image: url(icons/homeBlue.png)}
```

Then when you want to check the state of the DIV use e.g.:

```
     if ($('#myDIV').hasClass('state_3')) {......}
else if ($('#myDIV').hasClass('state_2')) {......}
else                                      {......}
```

To change the image, just change the class, e.g.

```
$('#myDIV').removeClass('state_1 state_3').addClass('state_2');
```

You'll have to handle hover events in jQuery, not just CSS, unless of course you could use the css modifiers ":hover", ":visited"

Comment: P.S. You can find the current background image in jQuery using: $('#myDIV').css('background-image'), but using classes is, in my opinion, a better way of implementing a tri-state solution.

Comment: For me the implication of this is that :hover is redundant as everything is handled in JQuery - in fact although CSS is used to declare a class in this reply the same could have been done in pure javascript without the CSS classes. Additionally using what was suggested in the comment returns the entire path - something I thought was overkill - and that was why I made this post.